# How does BuzzFeed do their mobile redirect?

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, nginx, varnish

I'm trying to add a mobile redirect to my site. I'm thinking I want a completely separate layout though, rather than using media queries.

One easy way to do this is to have CloudFlare detect and redirect to a subdomain `m.example.com`.

I don't want to use a subdomain though for several reasons.

The other way I did in the past was to use [this mobile detect script](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) with media queries and partially loading sections of the page. This proved to be a nightmare in the long run, and I don't want to use media queries.

I notice the way [buzzfeed.com](http://buzzfeed.com) does it is pretty much exactly how I want to do it. It looks like they somehow detect the browser or something, then redirect to ?s=mobile which displays the mobile site.

I can't tell if this is done on the server or in Javascript though, or how they're doing it. I assume it's on the server because if i `curl http://www.buzzfeed.com/?s=mobile` I get a `302` response... I'm guessing because curl isn't sending a header that looks like mobile.

Are there common, frequently-maintained scripts for nginx or varnish to do this? I'm mainly scratching my head and googling doesnt appear to be bringing up much relevant discussion other than weak-looking snippets from 3 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [varnish-devicedetect](https://github.com/varnish/varnish-devicedetect) VCL to accomplish everything you're looking for. The [installation guide](https://github.com/varnish/varnish-devicedetect/blob/master/INSTALL.rst) gives you examples on how to, for example, add query parameters to the request URL, or add custom headers to the request that is sent to the backend. That allows you to handle different types of clients transparently.

It takes quite a bit of thinking and fiddling to get all the Vary headers, purging etc. to work flawlessly, but with help from the examples you should be able to make varnish-devicedetect work for you.